# Execute stored procedure in python without return

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, stored-procedures, pymssql

I am using this code to execute SP in python

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server="myServer", database="myDB", port="1433", user="myUser", password="myPwd")
pd.read_sql("EXEC MySP", conn)
conn.close()
```

but I get this error

> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py",
>   line 1469, in read_query
>       columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

after doing some research I found the cause of the error is due to no returning value coming from the SP.

ok, my SP does not have any return value and I just want to execute this SP as is.

is there anyway I can do that without having this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks kjmerf

I just added `SELECT ''` at the end of my SP and that fixed the problem.

I thought there could be another function other than `read_sql` in pandas that might fix this but my search found non.

Comment: asmgx. im facing a similar problem. do you think you can share insight. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72209641/read-sql-stored-procedure-data-through-pyodbc-into-a-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import sqlalchemy

connection_string = 'mssql+pymssql://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}'.format(username = <username>, password = <password>, host = <host>, port = <port>, database = <database>)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string)
connection = engine.raw_connection()

try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.callproc('<procedure_name>')
    cursor.close()
    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

You have to input username, password, etc. in the connection string and your procedure name as an argument in the callproc method.

Comment: why do i need to create a cursor?!

Comment: See calling stored procedures section here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html

Comment: from that link engine.execute("***") seems much simpler

Comment: Whatever works. I had the same issue the other day and used the method above. Not claiming to be expert on this one.

Comment: @kjmerf hey, do you think you could help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72209641/read-sql-stored-procedure-data-through-pyodbc-into-a-dataframe